# How do I use sheets.AppendRow? I keep receiving an error [Ljava.lang.Object;@29080d11 in all the cells

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am retrieving the body of a email and inserting into google sheets. Keep getting [Ljava.lang.Object;@29080d11 errors. I already have retrieveing the data working well. I have a little problem with building the array to append to google sheets. This is my code;

```
function processInboxToSheet() {
  // var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("NEWNOPS");
  var label = 'Inbox';
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"New Quality Test Results"');
  // var threads = label.getThreads();
  // Set destination sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get all emails with subject  
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var tmp;
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];  // second message in thread
      content = message.getPlainBody();  // remove html markup

      // next three lines cleans the message to just the data

      content = content.substr(content.search("Tank 1"));  // remove beginning of trash 
      var n = content.lastIndexOf("INH");
      content = content.substr(0,(n+14)); // get the body of the wanted data 
      //Logger.log(n);
      content = content.split("\n"); // create array based on newline    
     var data = [];
                  data.push(content[0].match(/[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4}/)); //Date
                  data.push(content[1].match("")); //Blank  /\d*\.\d{2}/
                  data.push(content[2].match(/\d*\.?\d{2}/)); //Bfat
                  data.push(content[3].match(/\d*\.\d{2}/)); //Prot
                  data.push(content[4].match(/\d*\.\d{2}/)); //Lact
                  data.push(content[5].match(/\d*\.\d{2}/)); //OS
                  data.push(content[6].match(/\d*,\d{3}/)); //SPC
                  data.push(content[7].match(/\d*\,\d{3}/)); //SCC
                  data.push(content[8].match(/\d{2}/)); //MUN
                  data.push(content[9].match(/-\d.\d{4}/)); //FRZ
                  data.push(content[10].match(/\d{2}/)); //TMP
                  data.push(content[11].match(/\d/)); //INH

        Logger.log(data);      
    if (content) {
     sheet.appendRow(data);
      // if no match); display error
    } // End if

  } // End for loop
};
```

my data;

```
  Producer       32698-1          Date Of Notice     02/04/2020

       Cow Milker3

      8831 CHAPEL RD
       EASTERN, MD  21664




 Tank 1    Sample Date   02/03/2020   B O

 Bfat      4.09
 Prot      3.11
 Lact     4.720
 OS        5.64
 SPC      1,000
 SCC    100,000
 MUN         12
 FRZ    -0.5420
 TMP         37
 INH          0
```

Comment: SHould be tagged `java`.

Comment: Could you add any more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: You said "_I have a little problem with building the array to append to google sheets_". This is too vague; would you please explain in detail just what exactly is the problem that you are having?

Comment: @GetSet Google Apps Script returns that error when a multidimensional Array is passed as argument of `appendRow`

Comment: @Tedinoz ^^^^^^

Comment: @Tedinoz Ruben is right. Java error is because apps script was based on mozilla rhino: JavaScript>java translator of sort. new V8 isn't based on rhino

Comment: @TheMaster and Rubén. Timely heads up. I only noticed the message today in a project when I logged in today; I didn't realise the implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `match` returns an `Array` or `null`, so `data` is an "Array of Arrays" (multidimensional Array) but `appendRow` requires a 
"simple" Array.

Unfortunately there isn't a "simple fix" (like adding one code line or few characters). You should rethink the logic of your script to handle the case that there match returns `null` because it's not a valid value to be passed to Google Sheets.

Comment: This was the best help. changed logic to construct a new variable for each line and then push the "0" element into an array and then appendRow. works perfectly